# Optional variable (with default value) in custom function

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Is it possible to use an optional variable (**value2**) like

```
...
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def my_test(value1, value2=True, feature, parent)
....
```

in a custom function? Using QGIS 3.8

...like[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of a direct way but there is the [`handlesnull`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/7e7faadabf03051d748fa38bda1475a6ba0a6dc1/python/core/additions/qgsfunction.py#L54) flag which when set to true would let you input `NULL` as a parameter value.

```
...
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', handlesnull=True)
def my_test(value1, value2, feature, parent):
...
```

You might want to include some logic in your code to determine what happens when a parameter value is `NULL`.