# Defining a custom Python Expression function with default parameters

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-custom-function

Is it possible to use a variable with default value (value2) defined in a custom Python expression function?

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='UserFunction')
def my_test(value1, feature, parent, value2=True):
    if value2:
        return 100
    else:
        return 0
```

I know that this question was already asked years ago ([Optional variable (with default value) in custom function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340037/optional-variable-with-default-value-in-custom-function)) but I wonder if there is another way.
In Python, the default values are placed at the end. However, if I do that, the second does not change:

```
mytest(13, True) -> returns 100
mytest(13, False) -> returns 100
```

Comment: And with `handlesnull=True` in the decorator, with a `value2` arg just after `value1` and in the code `if value2 is None: value2 = True` ?

Comment: Thank you J! I know about this workaround but I wonder if there is another way to deal with default parameters.

Comment: Answer: no, currently there is no way of doing that. The docs say: "Define any parameters you want to pass to your function before the following arguments.", referring to `feature`, `parent` and optionally `context`. That is, `feature` and `parent` are mandatory and you cannot place any custom parameter after them (except by `context`, which is not a custom one). On the other hand, any attempt of placing a custom parameter with default value before the mandatory ones (`feature` and `parent`) will throw a Syntax Error from Python: `SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`.